# taskbars missing in NoMachine

Tags: nomachine

I use NoMachine to connect to a remote Linux machine.  Recently, my upper and lower taskbars have disappeared.  The main problem is that, if I minimize a window, I now have no way of retrieving it, since it is typically iconized in the upper taskbar.

The problem occurs regardless of what computer I log in from.  I've tried the following things, with no success:

- Changed the display options to see if these taskbars were simply off the screen.
- Delete the .nx directory in my home directory.
- Uninstall and reinstall NoMachine.
- Searched for the problem on Google and StackOverflow.

I've had this problem before, and I believe it resolved itself after a number of days, but I'd rather not wait and hope for something to change.  Has anyone heard of this problem before?

Alternately, if the primary problem has no clear solution, is there any way of retrieving minimized windows within NoMachine without using the taskbar (e.g. can I access those windows through a keyboard shortcut or the right-click window)?

I've attached an image of my workspace.  You can see the outer Windows taskbars, but typically there are two additional taskbars.

[Image of my NoMachine workspace.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKvfd.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I do not know the right solution to make the taskbar appear again, I think I have a workaround solution to retrieve minimized windows without using the taskbar. Switch to the fullscreen mode of NoMachine using `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F` and then use tab key to switch between open applications. Once the desired application window is back in view/focus, you may switch out of fullscreen mode by using `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F` again

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I switched away from NoMachine a while back, but I'm accepting this answer, since it appears to provide some helpful shortcuts.